# upper_bound function from a specific position instead of data.begin()

Tags: c++, search, c++11, stl

I am trying to find out from a sorted pair vector the first number greater than a given `Number`. I used `upper_bound` and it works well. The code is shown below:

```
bool cmp(int n, pair<int, int> const& p)
{    
    return (p.first > n) ;
}

vector<pair<int,int>> v;
vector<pair<int,int>>::iterator up;
//int Number = ...;
// .......
up = upper_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), Number, cmp);
```

Now I want to search from a specific position instead of the beginning. So I changed the code into:

```
up = upper_bound(v.at(i), v.end(), Number, cmp);
```

where `i` means that I want to search from the `ith` position of the vector `v` to end. However, it gives me an error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'upper_bound(__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::
allocator<std::pair<int, int> > >::
value_type&, std::vector<std::pair<int, int> >::iterator, int&, 
bool (&)(int, const std::pair<int,  int>&))'
```

What's the reason that caused such an error? And is there any better method to search from a given position?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::vector::at` does not return an iterator, which is what you need for `upper_bound`. You can obtain an iterator to the required position and pass it like this:

```
up = upper_bound(v.begin() + i, v.end(), Number, cmp);
```

or

```
up = upper_bound(std::next(v.begin(), i), v.end(), Number, cmp);
```